Assigning colours to categories ggplot scale_colour manual
I'm trying to use scale_colours_manual in ggplot just to set one colour and the rest be assigned just to the scheme provided. This is so if more categories appear once this is automated we won't have to adjust the code. I've tried something like this:
colours <- c("#12436D","#065e4c","#28A197","#1f6096","#27a0cc","A"="red","#a8bd3a")

But I get the chart below:

I'd like to end up with something like this:


It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a working example of your code and a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

for example:
library(ggplot2)

colours <- c("#12436D","#065e4c","#28A197","#1f6096","#27a0cc", 
  "audi" = "#666163", "dodge" = "#c80204", "chevrolet" = "#0474cc", 
  "ford" = "#00142e", "honda" = "#0a9be4", "hyundai" = "#012c5f", 
  "jeep" = "#f2b54b", "land rover" = "#005a7d", "lincoln"  = "#366d72", 
  "nissan"  = "#003f65", "pontiac" = "#c8242c", "subaru" = "#2c80b9", 
  "volkswagen" = "#5b07a4")

# these are all the unique names 
uniq <- unique(mpg$manufacturer)

# these are the unique names that are already in the colours vector
keep <- names(colours[names(colours) != ""])

# these are the unique names that are not yet in the colours vector
unas <- setdiff(uniq, keep)

# combine the two sets of colours
colours <- c(colours[keep], setNames(colours[1:length(unas)], unas))

ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = cyl, color = manufacturer)) +
    geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = colours)


Exactly this but I only want to assign one of the values a colour. This is because the other values may change month on month when this is automated.
